# Presto - hex string to int

Tags: sql, hex, presto

I'm trying to convert hex string (starts with '0x') to it's integer value using presto. For example `0x100` to 256. My hex string is called msg_id. 
I tried to use this-

```
from_hex(substr(msg_id,3))
```

But I run into a problem, because `from_hex` expect even number of hex digits (`0100` instead of `100`). 
I decided to try and solve this using an `if` statement, so I tried this:

```
if(length(msg_id)%2=0, from_hex(substr(msg_id,3)))
```

(will take care of the odd number of digits case later)

But- the result of `from_hex` is a `varbinary` type, with a varied number of bytes. I want to convert it to an Integer, or any other numeric type, but I can't find a way to do it.

Any ideas? I would appreciate it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`from_base(string, radix)`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/math.html#from_base) to parse number written with hex digits into a `bigint`. You just need to strip leading `'0x'` first:

```
select from_base(substr('0x100', 3), 16);
 _col0
-------
   256
```

or with [`regexp_replace()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_replace):

```
presto:tiny> select from_base(regexp_replace('0x100', '^0x'), 16);
 _col0
-------
   256
```