# Athena AWS - How Can Convert Binary to Bigint

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

How can i convert data from binary to bigint with athena aws?

In SQL SERVER I can do it this way

```
select convert(bigint, 0x00000000001F3111)

Result: 2044177
```

But I was unable to do this with Athena AWS. Is there any way for this?

Comment: That looks like Hex, not Binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample looks like Hex, not binary.

From [Presto - hex string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53979854/174777):

```
select from_base(substr('0x100', 3), 16);
 _col0
-------
   256
```

Comment: Tks, really is Hex ;-)